# How do I use Negotiate or Kerberos authentication with axios?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios

Using Axios in my client-side web code, can I make XHR web requests using Kerberos or Negotiate authentication?  I'd like the browser to supply the user's SPNEGO token just as a normal request via a link or the location bar would, via a user prompt or a single-sign-on for trusted URIs.

Everything I see is an example like this:

```
axios.get(url, {
  withCredentials: true,
  auth: {
    username: '...',
    password: '...'
  }
}
```

But that seems to try Basic auth.  I'd like to do Kerberos without supplying a username or password.  Is this possible?

Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On any request, Axios--or more precisely, the browser--will add the Negotiate SPNEGO token in the "Authorization" header automatically, if `withCredentials` option is set to true, as the example shows.  No `auth` option is necessary.

If this is part of a CORS request with preflight, the browser will automatically send an OPTIONS request if necessary, using no Authorization header.  There is nothing Axios does (or needs to do) to enable this behavior.

```
axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true })
```