# Kerberos SSO authorization from React

Tags: reactjs, rest, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

I have a React app that makes requests to our REST API server using axios.

On the REST server we use Kerberos for authorization. When I simply make a request to that server using chrome (through address bar like "https://example.com/api/v1/sso_auth"), the authorization works fine (chrome passes the correct header with kerberos's ticket data), but when the React App makes the request, the ticket isn't added to the request (stuck on `www-authenticate: negotiate` phase).

How can I access (or maybe intercept) the Kerberos ticket and send it via the react app using axios?

Comment: Did you configure the CORS response correctly? I have this setup and it works perfectly with Axios.

Comment: From last year: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314346/49849